# New installation of 16.04.1 keeps USB floppy drive seeking at all times while running

Tags: usb

New installation of 16.04.1 keeps USB connected floppy drive seeking (clunk sound) at all times while running unless I put a disk in.  Then it flashes the activity light at the same 2 ~ 3 second interval at all times.

The drive otherwise works.

This same machine runs Windoze 10 from a different (mechanically switched) hard drive, and does not have this problem at that time.

EDIT - I didn't mention the USB connected card reader / USB panel add on at first, but Windoze shuts it off at shut down, Ubuntu just leaves it running AFTER shut down. I have no idea how that is done, but it is, unless I unplug the system.

How can I fix this?  Are there supplemental USB drivers available, etc.?  ANY ideas?

Comment: Are you seriously talking about a floppy drive like those of the 80s?

Comment: Yes.  It reads (and writes, but I mainly need the read) 2.5" hard plastic floppies.

I have LOTS of info and data on these disks, and it would take literally years to get them transferred to other media, not to mention the cost of the media to do that.

Comment: A single CD-R can store more than 486 floppys. Honestly, you need a better excuse. Now, back to your problem, the only interesting info I could find is that Windows 10 dropped support for floppies so no surprise it stays quiet in Windows: The OS doesn't see it and doesn't care. There are a few convoluted methods (or so it seems) to re-enable it but, by default, Win10 doesn't read/write floppies. It's still supported in Ubuntu so the OS checking the drive is to be expected. Whether or not what you see is the normal behavior, I'm not competent to determine.

Comment: Windows 10 Anniversary edition does see it.  It works fine in all respects, including read, write, appear in directories, no continual seeks.

Comment: Shot down by the 5 minute rule, below is part of above.

I really hope you or someone can provide some info on how the system detects the floppy, and how it may be either temporarily shut down during boot (I can do this in "Drives - power off", but can't restart it without rebooting) and restarted in session, or fixed so it doesn't wear itself out being continually activated and re-activated by the system.  Even being able to toggle whether or not it starts in Ubuntu would be ok.

This might also be of interest to the developers.

Thanks!